# What is the simplest way to create a redirect

Tags: permalinks

If I have a custom post type called Drink which has permalinks like `/drink/pepsi/` then `/drink/` will list all of the Drinks. How can I rewrite `/drink/` to `/drinks/`?

I want permalinks for single Drinks `/drink/pepsi` to stay with the `/drink/` root but I think `/drinks/` makes better sense for the "archive" of Drink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you [register your custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type), set the `has_archive` argument to the slug you want for the archive page, in this case `drinks`:

```
$args = array(
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'drink' ),
    'has_archive' => 'drinks',
);
```